# Definition and declaration

Tags: c++

I'm studying the C++ programming language from the book "Programming principles and practice using C++". I'm an absolute beginner and I have a problem with a paragraph in my book because I can't understand what the author means:

> A declaration is a statement that gives a name to an object.
>
> A definition is a declaration that sets aside memory for an object.

At the beginning of the chapter the author taught me that a statement that introduces a new name inside a program and that sets aside memory for a variable is called definition.

Can you make an example of declaration and definition?

Comment: To my understanding, `definition = declaration + initialization`.

Comment: @AndyG so that means that when I just declare a variable I'm not setting aside memory for that variable ?